# Unable to manually upload SSL certificate for Heroku app

Tags: ssl, heroku

I used letsencrypt to generate the certificate and the private key. All tested fine. The I used `heroku cert:add` to add the cert and private key to my app:

```
sudo heroku certs:add --type=sni /etc/letsencrypt/live/appname.com-0001/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/appname.com-0001/privkey.pem --app appname
```

The command worked a few months back, and now it just show the following:

```
Usage: heroku certs:add CRT KEY
```

then it will stop executing. So What should I do to add the cert and private key to Heroku?? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue by removing `--type=sni`  in the original command, then everything works fine now.